# Angular + WordPress

Tags: wordpress, angular

I have a ticket sales form written in Angular. How can I insert this form on the main page of Wordpress site? May be with usingthe tag iframe or can there be better solutions for this task? Thank you for attention!

Answer (score 1):

I think a best solution to this is to create a new page template (you can google it to get more accurate info), see what is page templates [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/).

Basically, you will create a new file on your theme root, with the prefix `page-`, e.g: `page-tickets.php`. And then the very first thing that must appear on your page is a comment,like this: `// Template Name: Tickets Page`. Your page will be something like this:

```
<?php
// Template Name: Tickets Page
get_header();
?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
// Angular + Html codes here!
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
  <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
<script>angular and js imports</script>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

With that, when you will create a new page in `Pages -> New` (or edit), in the right bottom side will be available an option to you to choose a page template, like this:
[image]

That's all, I hope it helps you.

Comment: Will it be correct if I in head add `<base href="/"><link href="styles.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet"/>` and before close </body> `<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script>`. Then on page what I need add <app-root></app-root>, files put on root folder???

Comment: I'm not sure if I completely understand what you mean, sorry. You include this imports only in this page, not globally on your site, the most important thing is that. And for importings you can use the `get_stylesheet_directory_uri` function. I hope it helps